# Can I find which search terms my photos in Google+ will respond to?

Tags: google-plus, photos

When performing a search in Google Plus, magically queries for "beach, jewelry, etc." show relevant photos from your own library. I'd like to see all of the search terms each of my photos will respond to. Is this possible via the API or using any other means?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a library for accessing your stream data and content shared with you because some of this data is private and Google+ search only returns public data. If your content is public, you can use the [activities.search API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.search) to perform searches against Google+ but this cannot be personalized to your particular stream or scoped to a specific user.